# Why BeautifulSoup cannot scrape all the quotes on a website into a list?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

In this code, I am trying to scrape the entire website in order to extract all the quotes from Abraham Lincoln hopefully into a list. However, I am having issue to find the correct tag and/or attribute to get the job done. Could you please let me know if something I am missing?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

# Request to website and download HTML contents
url = 'https://www.brainyquote.com/authors/abraham-lincoln-quotes'
req = requests.get(url, timeout=1000)

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
raw = soup.find_all('div', style_="display: flex;justify-content: space-between")

print(raw)
```

which prints an empty list!

Comment: Site is protected by Cloudflare. Your less complex way out on this one is to use Selenium. Let me know if you'd like a solution based on Selenium.

Comment: Thanks Barry, I would appreciate a solution based on Selenium. I have never worked with it before,

Comment: you cant use request, use modern ways like Selenium or chrome dev tools to scrap.it's protected by Cloudflare protection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to get that info using Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')

chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,1080")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
url = 'https://www.brainyquote.com/authors/abraham-lincoln-quotes'
browser.get(url) 
quotes = [x.text for x in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@title="view quote"]'))) if len(x.text) > 5]
print(quotes)
```

Result in terminal:

```
["Sir, my concern is not whether God is on our side; my greatest concern is to be on God's side, for God is always right.", 'Give me six hours to chop down a tree and I will spend the first four sharpening the axe.', 'You can fool all the people some of the time, and some of the people all the time, but you cannot fool all the people all the time.', 'Most folks are as happy as they make up their minds to be.', 'I am not bound to win, but I am bound to be true. I am not bound to succeed, but I am bound to live by the light that I have. I must stand with anybody that stands right, and stand with him while he is right, and part with him when he goes wrong.', "I don't like that man. I must get to know him better.", 'We the people are the rightful masters of both Congress and the courts, not to overthrow the Constitution but to overthrow the men who pervert the Constitution.', "Don't worry when you are not recognized, but strive to be worthy of recognition.", 'Be sure you put your feet in the right place, then stand firm.', 'I am a slow walker, but I never walk back.', "When I do good I feel good, when I do bad I feel bad, and that's my religion.", 'I will prepare and some day my chance will come.', 'I am a firm believer in the people. If given the truth, they can be depended upon to meet any national crisis. The great point is to bring them the real facts.', 'I have always found that mercy bears richer fruits than strict justice.', 'My great concern is not whether you have failed, but whether you are content with your failure.', 'He has a right to criticize, who has a heart to help.', 'As I would not be a slave, so I would not be a master. This expresses my idea of democracy.', "The shepherd drives the wolf from the sheep's throat, for which the sheep thanks the shepherd as his liberator, while the wolf denounces him for the same act as the destroyer of liberty. Plainly, the sheep and the wolf are not agreed upon a definition of liberty.", 'The best way to get a bad law repealed is to enforce it strictly.', 'This country, with its institutions, belongs to the people who inhabit it. Whenever they shall grow weary of the existing government, they can exercise their constitutional right of amending it, or exercise their revolutionary right to overthrow it.', "I remember my mother's prayers and they have always followed me. They have clung to me all my life.", 'Labor is prior to, and independent of, capital. Capital is only the fruit of labor, and could never have existed if labor had not first existed. Labor is the superior of capital, and deserves much the higher consideration.', 'If this is coffee, please bring me some tea; but if this is tea, please bring me some coffee.', 'A house divided against itself cannot stand.', 'No matter how much cats fight, there always seem to be plenty of kittens.', 'The highest art is always the most religious, and the greatest artist is always a devout person.', 'A friend is one who has the same enemies as you have.', 'A woman is the only thing I am afraid of that I know will not hurt me.', 'Avoid popularity if you would have peace.', 'It has been my experience that folks who have no vices have very few virtues.', 'You cannot escape the responsibility of tomorrow by evading it today.', "How many legs does a dog have if you call his tail a leg? Four. Saying that a tail is a leg doesn't make it a leg.", 'Always bear in mind that your own resolution to succeed is more important than any other.', 'No man has a good enough memory to be a successful liar.', 'All that I am, or hope to be, I owe to my angel mother.', 'The philosophy of the school room in one generation will be the philosophy of government in the next.', 'Character is like a tree and reputation like a shadow. The shadow is what we think of it; the tree is the real thing.', 'I do the very best I know how - the very best I can; and I mean to keep on doing so until the end.', 'The ballot is stronger than the bullet.', 'I like to see a man proud of the place in which he lives. I like to see a man live so that his place will be proud of him.', 'Government of the people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the Earth.', 'My dream is of a place and a time where America will once again be seen as the last best hope of earth.', 'Those who deny freedom to others deserve it not for themselves; and under the rule of a just God, cannot long retain it.', 'Do I not destroy my enemies when I make them my friends?', 'Marriage is neither heaven nor hell, it is simply purgatory.', "With Malice toward none, with charity for all, with firmness in the right, as God gives us to see the right, let us strive on to finish the work we are in, to bind up the nation's wounds.", 'The probability that we may fail in the struggle ought not to deter us from the support of a cause we believe to be just.', 'Discourage litigation. Persuade your neighbors to compromise whenever you can. As a peacemaker the lawyer has superior opportunity of being a good man. There will still be business enough.', 'I do not think much of a man who is not wiser today than he was yesterday.', 'We should be too big to take offense and too noble to give it.', 'That some achieve great success, is proof to all that others can achieve it as well.', "No man is good enough to govern another man without the other's consent.", 'Tact is the ability to describe others as they see themselves.', "I don't know who my grandfather was; I am much more concerned to know what his grandson will be.", 'You have to do your own growing no matter how tall your grandfather was.', 'Surely God would not have created such a being as man, with an ability to grasp the infinite, to exist only for a day! No, no, man was made for immortality.', "The things I want to know are in books; my best friend is the man who'll get me a book I ain't read.", 'Every man is said to have his peculiar ambition. Whether it be true or not, I can say, for one, that I have no other so great as that of being truly esteemed of my fellow-men, by rendering myself worthy of their esteem. How far I shall succeed in gratifying this ambition is yet to be developed.', 'At what point then is the approach of danger to be expected? I answer, if it ever reach us, it must spring up amongst us. It cannot come from abroad. If destruction be our lot, we must ourselves be its author and finisher. As a nation of freemen, we must live through all time, or die by suicide.', 'Lets have faith that right makes might; and in that faith let us, to the end, dare to do our duty as we understand it.']
```

See [Selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/) for more.

Comment: To deal with error message, it seems I have to install the ChromeDriver on this page(https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/) however there are two versions named chrome and chromedriver for WIN64. Which one should I go about downloading?

Comment: I guess I don't know which packages to install in one go in a conda env. I only included selenium.

Comment: See [getting started](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/) on Selenium documentation. You can also do `service = Service()` then initialize the driver with `browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)` @Ash

Answer (score 1):

you cant use request, use modern ways like Selenium or chrome dev tools to scrap.it's protected by Cloudflare protection.

```py
import undetected_chromedriver as uc 

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

#options = Options()
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless=new')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu') 
options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36')
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
options.add_argument("--nogpu")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

#driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get('https://sample.com/')
print(driver.page_source)
driver.close()
```

sample code to use selenium to scrap the page and download the page as HTML.